# Xamarin forms testing layout

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xamarin, layout, xamarin.forms

```cs
var child = new Frame();
var relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout();
relativeLayout.Children.Add(child, Constraint.RelativeToParent(r => 42));

var x = child.X;

x.Should().Be(42);
```

I'm trying to test some logic related to the position of elements in my Xamarin Forms app. The problem is that `x` is 0 in this case, but in the running App, it is 42.
I know there is the concept of UI-testing, but I would not like to go down that road just yet.

Is there some way of forcing layout in the tests?

In WPF you can do `.Measure` and `.Arrange` to place items correctly.

Comment: I recommend [starting from some working example code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/samples/). Have you learned the steps of how X-Forms builds and displays a page?  `x` is zero because you are "too early" in the process - there is no layout yet - everything will be 0 or -1. See also: [The Xamarin.Forms book](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/). NOTE: book has not been updated since 2016; look for link "some of the material is outdated" and "Ways in which the book is outdated" on that page.